How to address aggressive bots scraping product search page
I'm using the Search API module and Solr to power my product listing page, which includes a faceted search with a relatively large number of filters. However, aggressive bot traffic has caused my site to exceed Acquia's Solr search thresholds.
I've attempted to mitigate this issue using our Web Application Firewall, but it feels like a game of whack-a-mole because these processes often use rotating IP addresses and user agents.
Upon examining the logs, I noticed that bots are aggressively targeting the filters on our main product listing page, systematically exploring every combination available. I believe that a typical site visitor would only use 2 to 5 filters before finding what they're looking for.
Therefore, implementing a limit on the number of filters that can be applied before presenting a 404 page might be an effective solution. While I understand this approach could potentially disrupt some legitimate user searches, the current situation is significantly impacting our site, sometimes resulting in users seeing an empty search page with thi error message.

Flood protection has blocked this Solr request.

Has anyone found an effective way to counter these aggressive processes?
If so, could you please share your solution?
Could Google or other legitimate search indexing processes penalize me for implementing this?
I am considering using the robots.txt file to deny access to this product listing page, which I believe should prevent any issues.
This the code I came up with to restrict the number of filters that could be applied.
use Drupal\search_api\Query\QueryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_query_alter().
 */
function my_module_search_api_query_alter(\Drupal\search_api\Query\QueryInterface &$query) {

  $conditions = $query->getConditionGroup()->getConditions();
  $condition_count = 0;
  foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    $condition_count += count($condition->getConditions());
  }

  if ($condition_count > 5) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }

}

I don't use the Acquia WAF. The one I use provides the ability to block individual IPs but that's about it. I blacklisted a sampling of the offender's IP addresses but it didn't seem to help for very long.
I'm not sure how a honeypot or CAPTCHA would help since this is simply a page that lists all our products and allows users to keyword search or apply filters to drill down to relevant products.

Would you please update this post to indicate the countermeasures you tried with the web application firewall?
Are there options with that WAF to just slow down responses on some paths? Are captchas an option here? The newest kind is basically invisible. Is honeypot module a possibility?

If you're worried about your current approach upsetting Google...it's usually considered best practice for these kinds of links to have a rel=nofollow on them anyway, which in your case would mean that Google would never get to the 404, so no penalty (in theory). Extending that (i.e. keeping the assumption search/links shouldn't be indexed), you could override the templates for the links, move the href into a data-href, then use JS to populate the href after pages load. Similar to the old lazyload image approach. That would at least raise the bar to bots who understand JS

I had a site that was getting hammered with spam bots registering fake accounts, and the CloudFlare free plan was a big help. It didn't totally eliminate the bots, but it blocked quite a lot of them. CloudFlare's stats suggested that in that site's case, 30% of the traffic was bots. There are several CDNs with bot-blocking capabilities, so I'd look into those.

@PatrickKenny Acquia WAF is a locked-down Cloudflare, which unfortunately means more advanced stuff that might help with flood/bot control is probably out of the OP's grasp

The Crawler Rate Limit module helped me in a similar situation you are in.
